# How do I create a common table expression with two derived tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, derived-table

So I tried to create this CTE with two derived tables. My first derived table will display account numbers, account descriptions for account numbers within the 500 range. The second derived table in the CTE - should list account numbers, invoice totals and invoice id’s that have an Invoice total greater than 1000.

Now I started with creating those two tables separately to make sure I know what I'm doing. They worked like this:

```
SELECT AccountNo, 
    AccountDescription
FROM Accounts
WHERE AccountNo BETWEEN 500 and 599

SELECT Accounts.AccountNo, 
    Invoices.InvoiceTotal, 
    Invoices.InvoiceID
FROM Accounts 
    JOIN InvoiceLineItems
        ON Accounts.AccountNo = InvoiceLineItems.AccountNo
    JOIN Invoices
        ON InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceID = Invoices.InvoiceID
WHERE Invoices.InvoiceTotal >= 1000
```

Now when I tried to turn them into a CTE, my best try looks like this:

```
WITH Accounts500to599 AS
(SELECT AccountNo, 
    AccountDescription
FROM Accounts
WHERE AccountNo BETWEEN 500 and 599
ORDER BY Accounts.AccountNo),

InvoicesAbove1000 AS 
(SELECT Accounts.AccountNo, 
    Invoices.InvoiceTotal, 
    Invoices.InvoiceID
FROM Accounts 
    JOIN InvoiceLineItems
        ON Accounts.AccountNo = InvoiceLineItems.AccountNo
    JOIN Invoices
        ON InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceID = Invoices.InvoiceID
WHERE Invoices.InvoiceTotal >= 1000
ORDER BY Accounts.AccountNo)
```

Now my final goal is to show accounts with invoices larger than the average invoice total, which should be simple enough, but I still have a lot to learn when it comes to creating these CTE's.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a bit of an expansion to **seanb**'s answer, here's how you might attempt to get your invoices greater than the invoices average. Take a look at the `WHERE`.

```
;WITH Accounts500to599 AS (
    SELECT
        AccountNo, 
        AccountDescription
    FROM AS Accounts
    WHERE
        AccountNo BETWEEN 500 and 599
),
InvoicesAbove1000 AS (
    SELECT
        Accounts.AccountNo, 
        Invoices.InvoiceTotal, 
        Invoices.InvoiceID
    FROM Accounts 
        JOIN InvoiceLineItems
            ON Accounts.AccountNo = InvoiceLineItems.AccountNo
        JOIN Invoices
            ON InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceID = Invoices.InvoiceID
    WHERE 
        Invoices.InvoiceTotal >= 1000
)
SELECT
    Accounts500to599.AccountNo,
    Accounts500to599.AccountDescription,
    InvoicesAbove1000.InvoiceID,
    InvoicesAbove1000.InvoiceTotal
FROM Accounts500to599
INNER JOIN InvoicesAbove1000
    ON Accounts500to599.AccountNo = InvoicesAbove1000.AccountNo
WHERE InvoicesAbove1000.InvoiceTotal > (
    
    SELECT 
        AVG( InvoiceTotal )
    FROM Accounts AS a
    INNER JOIN InvoiceLineItems l
        ON a.AccountNo = l.AccountNo
    INNER JOIN Invoices i
        ON l.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID
    WHERE
        a.AccountNo BETWEEN 500 AND 599
        AND i.InvoiceTotal > 1000

)
ORDER BY
    Accounts500to599.AccountNo;
```

Answer (score 2):

Treat the CTE as you would any other table (or a view). It creates a virtual table for use.

For example, in your above, you can do

```
WITH Accounts500to599 AS
(SELECT AccountNo, 
    AccountDescription
FROM Accounts
WHERE AccountNo BETWEEN 500 and 599
-- ORDER BY Accounts.AccountNo -- Note - removed the order by
),

InvoicesAbove1000 AS 
(SELECT Accounts.AccountNo, 
    Invoices.InvoiceTotal, 
    Invoices.InvoiceID
FROM Accounts 
    JOIN InvoiceLineItems
        ON Accounts.AccountNo = InvoiceLineItems.AccountNo
    JOIN Invoices
        ON InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceID = Invoices.InvoiceID
WHERE Invoices.InvoiceTotal >= 1000
--ORDER BY Accounts.AccountNo   -- Note - removed the order by
)

SELECT A.AccountNo, A.AccountDescription, AVG(I.InvoiceTotal) AS AvgInvoiceTotal
FROM   Accounts500to599 A
       INNER JOIN InvoicesAbove1000 I ON A.AccountNo = I.AccountNo
GROUP BY A.AccountNo, A.AccountDescription
```

This doesn't answer your 'invoices greater than average' as there are some questions about what that actually means when you already exclude invoices < $1000, but the above gives an example of how they can be used.

Note that the order of the data doesn't matter (just like normal tables) - therefore I commented out the ORDER BY clauses in the CTEs.

A traditional CTE is also functionally equivalent to a sub-query in the FROM clause - so the above is analagous to

```
SELECT A.AccountNo, A.AccountDescription, AVG(I.InvoiceTotal) AS AvgInvoiceTotal
FROM   (SELECT AccountNo, 
               AccountDescription
        FROM Accounts
        WHERE AccountNo BETWEEN 500 and 599
       ) A
       INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT Accounts.AccountNo, 
          Invoices.InvoiceTotal, 
         Invoices.InvoiceID
       FROM Accounts 
           JOIN InvoiceLineItems
                ON Accounts.AccountNo = InvoiceLineItems.AccountNo
           JOIN Invoices
                ON InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceID = Invoices.InvoiceID
      WHERE Invoices.InvoiceTotal >= 1000
    ) I ON A.AccountNo = I.AccountNo
GROUP BY A.AccountNo, A.AccountDescription
```